# how to release a view from ColorPickerImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

simply i have create view from "ColorPickerImageView.h" programtically and i wanna release this view.
every time I wanna release this view using [view removeFromSuperView] it gives me Bad access and the application crashes 
So, how to release Custom uview created by foundation framework

the link for the class:
http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/

Comment: Specifically, what's the Bad access say?

Comment: It should be overreleased. How do you create it? Are you adding it as subview? It can happen that the superview get released before you call removeFromSuperView]? Don't you call release before? Please provide more code. Are you using ARC?

Answer (score 0):

If you created ColorPickerImageView through **alloc** keyword, then Just call **release** to it after added as **subview**.

**removeFromSuperView** is automatically done for you when self.view is actually **deallocated**, so you don't need to do it yourself.

if you call **removeFromSuperView** for an already removed object or twice for an object, the application will crash.

Comment: i have the same problem but when i call the parent view 
[ParentView RemoveFromSuperView]; my app crashes because of bad access

Comment: did you call removeFromSuperView for an already removed object or twice for an object?